# How to process ajax response that stop working?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a server request through ajax with a response from php and this is the json response.

```
1[1, "provide", "4", "00956068", "6"]
```

but I can't make use of this response at all.

my JavaScript

```
   function check_nh()

      {
    var action; var nhis = $('#rid').val();

  $.post('server.php',{
    nhisid : nhisid ,
     action : 'Check' },
       function(data) {

        if(data[0]==0){
          $('#nhis_st').html('Unknown Provider')
             }else{


    $('#np').html(data[1]);
    $('#nh').html(data[3]);
    $('#nh').val(data[2]);
      if(data[4]== 2 ){
         $('#nh').html('Active');
               }else if(data[4]== 6){
                  $('#nhi').html('Already in use by Another user');
         }else{
           $('#nhi').html('Pending Registration'
);}
     }  
   },"json");
}
```

thanks for your response , here is my complete Server code:

```
function  check($id,$conn){
     $query = $conn->prepare("select * from tblReg where ID=?");
        $exe = $query->execute(array($id));
          $row =$query->rowCount();
            $result = list($a,$b,$c,$d) = $query ->fetch( PDO::FETCH_NUM );
              return 
                  array($row,$result[0],$result[1],$result[2],$result[3]);
                 exit();
                        }


            if(isset($_POST['check'])){

                 $jsonval =nhis_check($_POST[nhisid],$conn); 
                      echo json_encode($jsonval);
                         exit();
                            }
```

Comment: There's something in your PHP code that's echoing a number before it does `echo json_encode($ar)`.

Comment: remove the echo that results in 1 your response should only be json no other. in your response you get text and json. include all the code for server so we can help determine which the other echo

Comment: Sounds like something spitting out the string version of a boolean. Possibly debug code for sql functions. Without your server-side php, we can only guess.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Presumably this line in your example is just a typo `$ar = array($row,$vala,$valb)` (no `;` at the end)?

Comment: _“here is my complete Server code”_ - can’t be, you are trying to call a function `nhis_check` that does not exist anywhere in there. Despite the chosen nickname not even “astute” enough to post the actual code for the problem ...

Comment: Thank you all , i have figured it out. the 1 was from one of my include page thanks